# TextField in CGI perl

Tags: perl

```
     #!/usr/bin/perl -w

     use strict;
     use warnings;
     use CGI; 
     use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
     use CGI::textfiled;        

     my $q =CGI->new;
     print $q->header;
     print $q->start_html('onSite');
     print $q->end_html; 

     print $q->textfiled(
              -name => 'UserName',
              -value =>'defualt value',
              -size  => 30,
              -maxlength =>50,
      );
```

I am using the code and saved as .pl file and  running in the browser . I am getting the message in the web browser as
               Undefined subroutine CGI::textfiled
               at /var/www/cgi-bin/Ams.pl line 14

what are the things i have to update for CGI textfield

Comment: `textfiled` != `textfield`.

Comment: Looks like you need Symbol::Approx::Sub (https://metacpan.org/module/Symbol::Approx::Sub) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Spelling is wrong. It's `textfield`, not `textfiled`.